# Continuously Operating Reference Station (CORS) or other passive corrections for "regular people"

Tags: gps

My team is working on an autonomous car-type-mobile-robot-thing and we're looking to get some sort of corrected GNSS up and running for real-time high-precision positioning. A constant bias is fine, we mainly want a sub-meter(ish) precise offset from the robot's starting position.

I'm aware that Continuously Operating Reference Stations (CORS) exist in the area we'll need to operate our robot. I just have no idea what sort of equipment/software we'd need to use CORS for realtime positioning.

We did look pretty closely at RTK, but aren't able to use it because we'd need an internet connection. Whatever system we use for this can only have the robot receiving data, not sending any (concerns about radio interference with other robots). However, we do have access to RTK hardware and software if there is somehow a way to use it without internet.

I'm also aware of the Wide Area Augmentation System (WAAS) in the US, but from what I've read, this won't deliver the precision we're looking for - please correct me if I'm wrong.

Overall, does anyone know of other options and how to actually implement a correction solution? I can find lots of information online about how these systems work, but haven't had much luck finding out how to actually use them.

Comment: Here is a cellular RTK system:  https://www.microstrain.com/inertial-sensors/3dm-gq7?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=microstrain-inertial-namerica&sc=sensing-microstrain-google_adwords_fy22&utm_content=rtk&gclid=CjwKCAiA0JKfBhBIEiwAPhZXD3fBvaYSPgvVi2HeEuIeQJN8BHcj5Xwq4c-wnXFENg1HpSTwWUu5rBoCHBgQAvD_BwE

Comment: @GBG thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, that won't work for our case because it requires the cellular modem for an internet connection. That results in receiving data to the robot AND sending from, which the competition rules prohibit.

Comment: Most RTK methods use radio broadcast from a base station. So you have 2 units--one or more rovers and a base. Many cities have at least one public utility that broadcasts these corrections by radio from several base stations.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] that explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Unfortunately, discussion-oriented Questions that attempt to compile a list of opinions are off-topic here. This would be on-topic in [Chat], but Chat has a minimum reputation requirement and doesn't get the volume of visitors necessary to make it worth the effort.

Comment: @dustinrichards OK, I thought maybe it was the wifi that was the problem and that cellular would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using CORS as a base station, you could use your own local base station.  Surveyors and other Geospatial professionals have been doing that for years.  With that setup, you'd have a stationary GNSS "Base" receiver somewhere near where you are operating, with a radio link (typically 450MHz or 900MHz band depending on regulations in your area) broadcasting corrections.

Your "Rover" (our professional for your "car-type-mobile-robot-thing") would then have a 450MHz or 900MHz receive-only radio which receives corrections and feeds those to the GNSS to do real-time corrections.  For the sub-meter level of performance, you could probably get away with using DGNSS (Differential GNSS corrections) which are probably cheaper than RTK corrections (GNSS receivers can be cheaper, etc.)

As a low-cost option, I know that low-cost u-Blox receivers can be set up as base stations and rovers, but I've never done that.  Here's the [product page for the u-Blox C94-M8P](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/c94-m8p) - This is a development board that could be the basis of a base station, then you could use a similar M8 GNSS receiver with the radio on your rover.  Details left to you.  I guess the u-blox site will have application notes which show most of what you want to do.

I have no association with u-blox, but my company uses M8N and M8T GNSS receivers in our products, they work well at a reasonable price.

One last word here - GNSS accuracy is highly dependent on signal quality so fit the biggest, most expensive antenna you can onto your base and rover.